# Java function variables with default value

Tags: java

I have some function in java and i want this function to have a parameter with a default value that is set to variable if no value sent, look like following:

```
private void test(int count=5)
 {
 }
```

So i can call the function with 2 ways:
`test();` and `test(10);`

how do i do it?

Comment: Use overloading.

Comment: or use Integer --> if null then initialize variable to 5

Comment: @LaurentB  That still requires that a null be passed ..?

Answer (score 5):

You could have two overloaded methods.  The version with no parameters would call another version accepting an `int` input, passing a default value of 5.

```
private void test() {
    test(5);
}

private void test(int count) {
    // rest of method
}
```